# How did they deduce that this integral is equal to 0

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

[image]

I don't quite understand the solution to this question, which is :

[image]

What I don't understand is how do they calculate that the joint density integrates to 0? What is the joint density(if there exists one at all) ?

Comment: $X$ is discrete, so [...]

Comment: "it would have to satisfy $f_{XY}(x,y) = 0$ for any $x \notin \{0,1\}$"; thus the integrand vanishes almost everywhere.

Comment: @DanielFischer what do you mean by "almost everywhere''?

Comment: @ThePoorJew "Almost everywhere" means, in this context, "everywhere except a set of Lebesgue measure 0," or, "everywhere except a set that would not contribute to an integral." The idea is that a double integral on the rectangle $[0, 1]^2$ would not be affected by what happens only on the lines $x = 0$ and $x = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

distribution support should belong to Borel $\sigma$-algebra, thus it should have some area, here support for distribution $(X, Y)$ are only 2 lines which have area of 0 thus integral is = 0